# perform jquery .click() on page using iframe's content

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, parent-child

If possible, can I click on an element in an iframe and have that perform a function on the page it is rendered on?

for example:

```
<div class="page">

    <iframe class="frame">[... the source will render: <div class="clickme"></div>...] 
    </iframe>
```

...meanwhile, back on the main page...

```
    <script>
          $(".clickme").click(function(){
                 alert('clicked');
           });
    </script>
</div>
```

**edit** also, I forgot to mention that the iframe's src changes after the page loads, this could be an obstacle!

It doesn't seem to work for me and I couldn't find an appropriate answer/question here. Thanks!

Comment: When you say click on an item in the iframe, do you mean the user will click on the item in the iframe, or are you programmatically clicking the item in the iframe?

Comment: it loads different <div> but they all will have the same class regardless of which loads...I'm using it as a search box, so after they search it loads the new src with the results in the iframe

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean, but yes the user will click on an object in the iframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the user clicking on an item in the iframe should result in a function firing in the parent, then the following will work, assuming you have a function called `doStuff` in the parent:

```
window.top.doStuff();
```

Of course, this requires the domain of the iframe to match the domain of the parent page.

### **What if it needs to be cross-domain?**

If you require cross-domain communication, then the HTML5 postMessage function will empower you to register the parent page as a listener to the iframe, allowing the iframe to pass messages to the parent page.

**In the parent HTML, register a listener:**

```
// register to listen for postMessage events
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);  

// this is the callback handler to process the event
function receiveMessage(event)  
{  

  // you're responsible for your own security. Make sure requests are 
    // coming from domains you whitelist!
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.org:8080")  
    return;  

  if(event.data == "click!") {
      // do your stuff on the parent page here
  }
}
```

**In the iframe HTML page:**

```
// pass the string "click!" to the parent page, where the receiveMessage
 // handler will take action when it sees the message matches.
top.window.postMessage("click!", targetOrigin);
```

See [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! it works now!! I wasn't using good 'ol javascript onclick like I should have. @jmort253, I'm glad to keep giving you all these points hahah... thanks for all your help lately!

Answer (score 2):

You can access element in iframe using content()

```
$('.frame').contents().find('.clickme').each(function(){
   $(this).click(function(){ //this is .clickme
     //enter code here
   })
});
```

**note** if iframe's src come from different domain you 'll get access denied.

Comment: Thanks, i'm having trouble working this out still...Would it matter if the content of the iframe changes after the page loads?

Answer (score 1):

you can call a function in the Iframe,

```
window.frames['iframeName'].yourFunction();
```

and in the Iframe

```
    <script>
              $(".clickme").click(function(){
                      yourFunction();
               });

             function yourFunction(){
              alert('clicked');
             }
   </script>
```

Comment: thanks! so I would need to set the function for the specific iframe, and then I can use that function in the iframe?

Comment: Note that this only works if the domain of the iframe matches the domain of the parent document.